# Why won't my range for loop change elements?

Tags: c++, for-loop

I'm using this for loop to change all letters in a string to X.

```
string word{"banana"};
for (auto i : word) 
    i = 'x';//why does this bit fail?
cout << word;
```

The output is supposed to be xxxxxx, instead its "banana" even though the loop works.

Comment: C++ has value semantics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use &i like so:

```
auto &i : word
```

`i` in your case stores a copy of the original element, so whatever changes you make to it are lost.

Answer (score 1):

The the comments try to tell you is that your loop variable `i` is initialized *by value* meaning it's a copy of the value in the container, and you only modify the copy.

If you initialize *by reference* it will work.

Comment: It works! I've seen this before, but didnt understand what the & was for since my program worked fine when just printing elements. I have a follow up question hmmm, why is sometimes && used istead of a single &? –  Benjamin K 9 mins ago

Comment: @BenjaminK It's commonly known for [rvalue references](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11#Rvalue_references_and_move_constructors).